# Implementing network protocol in Clojure with Gloss

Tags: clojure, network-programming, network-protocols

I'm going to implement a complex, dynamic, binary protocol in Clojure using Aleph and Gloss.
Now, Aleph is awesome and Gloss makes things much easier, but protocol in question has lots of optional fields.

Q: Can a Gloss' [header->body function](https://github.com/ztellman/gloss/wiki/Introduction#headers) return another header? Or should I dynamically build the map to be compiled into codec?

And more general question: Are there any best practices or examples of building dynamic network protocols in clojure?